# Prove an implication about quadratic form definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Sylvester's criterion states that a quadratic form $q$ over an $n$-dimensional real linear space $V$ is positive definite $\iff$ all main minors $\Delta_1, \Delta_2, ..., \Delta_n > 0$. In Kostrikin's "Linear Algebra II" there are two implications proved to prove this theorem. I understand the $\impliedby$ implication (which is based on Jacobi's method to find canonical base), but I have a problems with $\implies$ part. Here is how it is stated there (my annotations in parentheses):

In accordance to the above $\Delta_1, \Delta_2, ..., \Delta_n > 0\implies$ $q$ is positive definite (this is $\impliedby$ part already done). To prove $\implies$ we do induction with respect to $n$ considering truncation $\bar{q}=q_{|U}$ of the form $q$ to $n-1$ dimensional subspace $U=\langle e_1, e_2, ..., e_{n-1}\rangle  \subset V=\langle e_1, e_2, ..., e_n\rangle $  (here $(e_i)$ is a base in which form $q$ has matrix $F$).
Main (principal) minors of $\bar{q}$ are obviously $\bar{\Delta}_1=\Delta_1, \bar{\Delta}_2=\Delta_2, ..., \bar{\Delta}_{n-1}=\Delta_{n-1}$. Because we assume now that form $q$ is positive definite so that is the $\bar{q}$ and **therefore based on induction's statement** (assumption) $\Delta_1, \Delta_2, ..., \Delta_{n-1} > 0$. We have to prove yet that $\Delta_n > 0$. (This is easy because $\Delta_n =\det F=\det A^TA=(\det A)^2> 0$.)

What was the (hidden - author didn't mention it) induction statement and induction step in this proof? Could someone please write the logic of the proof step by step? Thank you.

Comment: Since $q$ is positive definite then $\overline{q}$ is too, but $\overline{q}$ is defined on a vector spcae of dimension $n-1$. Thus, by induction on the dimension its main minors are positive. As you notice they are the first $n-1$ main minors of $q$. Thus it remains to prove that the last main minor is positive. The induction was used to garantee that the first $n-1$ minors were positive.

Comment: @Daniel "Thus, by induction on the dimension its main minors are positive." - but the fact that if q is positive then minors are positive is what we have to PROVE now

Comment: We want to prove => in statement: quadratic form $q$ over an $n$-dimensional real linear space $V$ is positive definite $\iff$ all main minors $\Delta_1, \Delta_2, ..., \Delta_n > 0$

Comment: Hi @odoa. The induction is on the dimension of $V$. If $\dim(V)=1$ then the result is obvious. ASSUME the result is true for $\dim(V)=n-1$. Let's prove it for $\dim(V)=n$. Let $q$ be a positive definite quadratic form over a n-dimensional vector space. We noticed that $\overline{q}$ is a positive definite quadratic form over a $n-1$-dimensional vector space, thus by our assumption (induction hypothesis) its main minors are positive. The main minors of $\overline{q}$ are the first $n-1$ main minors of $q$. The last minor of $q$ is positive by your argument. Thus, we completed the induction.

Comment: @Daniel yes, that's it, you can post this as an answer, but I think we should first show that result is true for n=2, because for n=1 it is trivial. Then we show that it is true for any n, based on fact that n-1 is positive definite. The result for n comes always from the fact that $\det A^TA = ( \det A )^2>0$

Comment: @Daniel thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome.